# Cannot use filter inside Django template html

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have an issue on my Django project. I have a situation as follows:

```
{% for subObject in mainObject.subObjects.all %}
```

This works nice, every `subObject` gets iterated nicely. What I want now is that I print a subset of the objects, something like:

```
{% for subObject in mainObject.subobjects.filter(someField=someValue) %}
```

So far I have searched solutions about the error I get:

```
Could not parse the remainder: '(someField=someValue)'
```

but did not find a solution about how the line should be different when a filter is used. I want to tweak just the `template.html` file, thus I don't want to make the change on `views.py` file (where everything supposedly would work nicely).

How to achieve this?

Comment: Do it in the view. That is the only way. You cannot use python in the templates. If you want to be able to do stuff like that, look into `jinaj2` as a replacement template engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @Yuji'Tomira'Tomita's comment..

Don't put too much logic into the template, quote from [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/):

> Philosophy
>
> If you have a background in programming, or if you’re used to
>   languages which mix programming code directly into HTML, you’ll want
>   to bear in mind that the Django template system is not simply Python
>   embedded into HTML. This is by design: the template system is meant to
>   express presentation, not program logic.

Better define the queryset in the view and pass to the template:

view:

```
def my_view(request):
    ...
    my_objects = mainObject.subobjects.filter(someField=someValue)
    return render(request, 'mytemplate.html', {'my_objects': my_objects})
```

template:

```
{% for subObject in my_objects %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. That request variable thing is awesome idea!

Comment: Actually, this set of subObjects is already inside a loop of mainObjects, and everything is given in megalomanic mainmainObject, but adding the def in proper place in model may make it. Anyways, thanks to pointing me to use code vs html for the logic.

Comment: @mico sure, it's a common problem of not having an ability to do smth in the template, but this is how things are done, templates are for representation purposes, for showing the data, not querying and filtering..separation of concerns (MVC) was a great invention :)