# Django: looping through filtered list in template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-filter

I have an html template where I would like to loop through objects in a model (`SpeciesPage`) which are filtered by a certain field value (`subfamily_name="Pierinae"`) and display them in a list. The filtered results span multiple foreign key relationships. Ultimately, I want the template to loop through and display multiple filtered results in separate lists, but I cannot get anything to render looping through one filtered list. I feel like what I'm trying to accomplish should be simple.

models.py (abbreviated to show only relevant fields)

```
class Subfamily(models.Model):
    subfamily_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Tribe(models.Model):
    subfamily = models.ForeignKey(Subfamily, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    tribe_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Genus(models.Model):
    tribe = models.ForeignKey(Tribe, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    genus_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Species(models.Model):
    genus = models.ForeignKey(Genus, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    species_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    species_page = models.OneToOneField('SpeciesPage', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

class SpeciesPage(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
    species_name = models.OneToOneField(Species, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

views.py

```
class SpeciesPageListView(generic.ListView):
    model = SpeciesPage
    template_name = 'speciespage_list.html'

def show(request):
    pierinae_pages = SpeciesPage.objects.filter(species_name__genus__tribe__subfamily__subfamily_name="Pierinae")

    context = {
        'pierinae_pages': pierinae_pages,
    }

    return render(request, 'speciespage_list.html', context=context)
```

speciespage_list.html

```
...
{% for speciespage in pierinae_pages %}
    <tr>
        <td><i>{{ speciespage.title }}</i></td>
        ...
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
...
```

I used the following answers from here in an attempt to solve my problem:

- [Cannot use filter inside Django template html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22621645/cannot-use-filter-inside-django-template-html)
- [Iterate over model instance field names and values in template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170228/iterate-over-model-instance-field-names-and-values-in-template)

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things:

You don't want to put `OneToOneField` in both `Species` and `SpeciesPage` pointing to each other. (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/ for details)

I think you can simplify your `ListView` to get the desired output:

```
class SpeciesPageListView(generic.ListView):
    model = SpeciesPage
    template_name = 'speciespage_list.html'
    queryset = SpeciesPage.objects.filter(species_name__genus__tribe__subfamily__subfamily_name="Pierinae")
    context_object_name = 'pierinae_pages'
```

and then in urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.SpeciesPageListView.as_view(), name='index'),
]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, simplifying my ```ListView``` like you described produced the desired result! Also, thanks for the info and link about ```OneToOneFields```, I didn't realize it was bad practice to have them point to each other.